# Accessing web Directory using python

Tags: python, ldap

I want to access the student details of all the students from the following college website https://java.access.uni.edu/ed/faces/searchStudent.jsp
I dont know the names of students and I want to access the details of each student .
The directory is open and there is nothing illegal in it .
I am using the following github code as a reference .
https://github.com/JoshuaRLi/direktory/blob/master/direktory.py
Please help !

Comment: your question is not even a question ,if you be more specific about what you want to do maybe someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it Using `bs4 beautifulsoup` which will help you to scrap the content from the given directory ... its basically called web scraping ..

that's  what represented in your github link...

another method is, [selenium webdriver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) .. 
from this method, you can simply pass the url followed by giving corresponding field name and its value.

you can trigger the API URL from selenium itself...

other you can send POST request and get response directly using **python requests** method...

here is the eg:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post("https://java.access.uni.edu/ed/faces/searchStudent.jsp;jsessionid=e8093da105003620293edb31ec442edfdfa514485389b950c4f20b46515aa640.e34Sbx0MaNuObi0LahiMaxmRb30Re0", data={'txtLastName':'mohamemd','txtFirstName':'mohideen','txtEmail':'temp@mail.com','soMajor':0,'soCollege':0,'soClass':0})
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text[:300]
u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"\r\n"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">\r\n    <head id="head1"><title>UNI Directory - Student Search</t'
>>> a = r.text[:300]
>>> len(a)
300
>>>
```

here i restricted output into 300.. if you want full you can simply print,

```
r.text
```

Comment: I dont know the names of students in advance and I need to access all the student names and their details in the directory . Any help ?

Comment: for that we need to know about API how it looks

Comment: The site does not provide any API for this

Comment: " https://java.access.uni.edu/ed/faces/searchStudent.jsp;jsessionid=e8093da105003620293edb31ec442edfdfa514485389b950c4f20b46515aa640.e34Sbx0MaNuObi0LahiMaxmRb30Re0", data={'txtLastName':'mohamemd','txtFirstName':'mohideen','txtEmail':'temp@mail.com','soMajor':0,'soCollege':0,'soClass':0})"  this is the api URL i found from that

Comment: Actually I want to get the data of each student that exist in the database or directory . Not just one .How can I do that ? Can you give the code so that I can see and understand it ?